# SQL two multi-row counts in one query

Tags: sql, count

I have got two queries:

```
select m.name, count(distinct a.kursnr)
from trainer t
left outer join mitarbeiter m 
on t.svnr = m.svnr 
left outer join einzeltraining e 
on t.svnr = e.trainer
left outer join abhaltung a 
on t.svnr = a.trainer 
group by m.name, t.svnr;

select m.name, count(e.trainer)
from trainer t 
left outer join mitarbeiter m 
on t.svnr = m.svnr
left outer join einzeltraining e 
on e.trainer = t.svnr 
group by m.name, e.trainer;
```

The first one returns the correct number of courses (kursnr) and the second number the correct number of individual classes (einzeltraining) hold by a trainer. However, I cannot make one SQL statement which shows both values in one table. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can't you just change the order of the second one to name, count(e.trainer), and use UNION to join the results together?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work because the values are shown in one column then, but I would like two columns.

Comment: Please add the table aliases to the columns--particularly in the ON and GROUP BY clauses!

Comment: It may help if we knew which tables each column comes from. One way you could help to indicate this to us would be to be consistent and use the `alias.column` form for *every* column reference in your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added them.

Comment: If we had sample data and desired results (and/or table creation scripts), we could probably knock out (some) duplicated table references.  Including a column in a `GROUP BY` but **not** in the `SELECT` list will make your results mysterious - there would be multiple rows, but no way to tell which `trainer.svnr` they belonged to: avoid this.  I'm also not completely convinced you want _only_ `LEFT JOIN`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is likely a more efficient way to do this, I wanted to show you the easy way to combine any two queries that share a common field such as this:

```
select coalesce(q2.name, q1.name) As Name, q1.KursnrCount, q2.TrainerCount
from 
(   --original first query
    select m.name, count(distinct a.kursnr) as KursnrCount
    from trainer t
    left outer join abhaltung a 
    on t.svnr = a.trainer 
    left outer join mitarbeiter m 
    on t.svnr = m.svnr 
    left outer join einzeltraining e on svnr = e.trainer
    group by m.name, t.svnr
) q1
full join 
(   --original second query
    select count(e.trainer) as TrainerCount, m.name
    from trainer t 
    left outer join einzeltraining e 
    on e.trainer = t.svnr 
    left outer join mitarbeiter m 
    on t.svnr = m.svnr
    group by e.trainer, m.name
) q2 on q2.name = q1.name
```

You could also use an inner join or left join, instead of a full join, depending on how the name fields from those queries match up.